# should white text be knockout for logo on top of a background?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

I am creating a simple logotype with a background box. The box is black and the text ontop is white.

I am using this logo for web and print. I have turned the text into outlines and then I have combined them using the pathfinder minus front. this has made the white text knockout and the back of the text is now transparent.

Is the best way to do this? I would like to know if I am making a mistake and if the text should not be combined this way with the background using pathfinder?

Can someone please let me know what is the best way for me to approach this?

Comment: It depends... if the text is to *always* be white.. then no.... if the text should adapt to any color the logo is sitting on... then yes.

Answer (score -1):

have block on layer 1. have text on layer 2 (converted to outlines).
make block black. make text white. you can always do the minus front later on, but it is good to be able to change the colour of the text in case that is needed in the future. :)

Comment: I don't think that's what's being asked